# getting image url from google contact api

Tags: google-maps, google-api

I am using google contacts api for getting my contacts information.
I am getting data through this url to generate feed and then parsing this feed to get the data.

I am able  to get email and name of my contacts but unable to get image of my contact.

Can somebody please help me in this

Comment: What is the URL you're using? You forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Send a [GET request](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/index#contact_photo_management) with the `userEmail` and `contactID`. Assuming that the contact has a photo, you'll receive a link which you can use to access the photos. Keep in mind this requires authentication.